# VSTS custom Task release run powershell on agent machine

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, task, working-directory

I created a custom vsts task that merge web.config files and I want to used it in my release pipeline, my task is a powershell and i want to run this powershell on agent machine but it runs in different directory when I give it the source folder it can't find it.
How to change powershell directory to make this task run on agent machine.
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you don't use the hosted agent and try to use your own dedicated agent for the build pipeline

Comment: How do you pass inputs to the powershell-script ? maybe this is your problem. Can you pls share that part of your code ?

Comment: @Jayendran how to check that ?

Comment: @D.J. the inputs are passing fine the problem is that the powershell script executed in a different directory not where on my agent machine

Comment: @MohamedBassuni First, make sure you installed [self- own agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) then, You need to check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdWUs.png)

Comment: 'not where on my agent machine '  so is the task using the wrong working directory or is it running in the wrong machine ?

Comment: @MohamedBassuni did you solve the issue ?

Comment: @Jayendran yes it works now fine as I changed agent pool not to windows hosted container but to default then i added Agent.Name equals my agent name.

Comment: @MohamedBassuni cool, I've formatted my comment as the answer.Please accept it

Answer (score 0):

By default, the build pipeline will be used the hosted agent, which provided by AzureDevOps.In your case, you need to change this behavior since you need to run your PowerShell script in your machine directory.

[image]

For that first, you need to install your [self-own agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts). Then you can point the directory to your PowerShell script which you'd like to run